# Locallibrary error 126 in Java with LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, loadlibrary, slick2d

I'm running into a problem configuring Eclipse IDE with Slick2D/JLWGL, I've set it up successfully on both my 32bit and 64bit windows machines, but for some reason I'm hitting an error on my newest 64-bit machine (running Win7).

Here is my project setup within Eclipse, I've imported the Slick2D and the most recent JLWGL libraries into my project and added them to the build path.
[image]

I've also imported the 64bit native libraries for JLWGL and set the proper native library path.

I'm getting the following error...
[image]

For reference here's the BasicGame class that's producing the error.

```
package fogtest;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class FogTest extends BasicGame {

    public FogTest(){
        super("test");
    }

    public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics arg1) throws SlickException {
    }

    public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {

    }

    public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException{
        AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new FogTest());
        app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        app.start();
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might be missing some transient dependencies?  Try opening each library in http://www.dependencywalker.com/ (an official-ish MS tool, see e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256872), and check it doesn't report any errors?

Comment: Looks like I'm dealing with a driver/hardware issue between my Radeon and OpenGL.  I'll post an update when I get to the bottom of it.  Thanks for the dependency idea though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a hardware issue with openGL, while my laptop manufacturer has blocked the most recent drivers from the card manufacturer I was able to find some people who ported the drivers for my machine.

Nothing more to see here, move along :-)